# Excel SLOPE function returning incorrect values

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, excel-2016

I seem to have stumbled upon a bug where the `SLOPE` function returns values when it shouldn't. Specifically, consider the following case (where X = `2.69896131835952`):

[image: SLOPE for X = 2.69896131835952]

[If the X values are always the same, `SLOPE` is supposed to return #DIV/0!](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SLOPE-function-11fb8f97-3117-4813-98aa-61d7e01276b9). But in the first case it returns 0, and more worryingly in the second case it returns some completely bogus number.

If we compare to other values, we can see this isn't normal behaviour:

[image: SLOPE with other X values]

This problem isn't fixed by using `ISNUMBER` to make sure to filter out empty results or similar. It can even happen to numbers with only a few decimal places (these numbers are exactly as shown):

[image: SLOPE giving incorrect data with 5dp numbers]

In fact, this isn't a very rare phenomenon at all - if one uses `RAND` to pick a single random value for X, and several random values for Y then it only takes a few tries before one finds a dataset which SLOPE hiccups on.

My questions are as follows:

1. What's causing this behaviour?
2. For which values of X does this happen for?
3. The above was only in the case where the X value is the same for every point. Obviously this is easy to test for in advance, but is `SLOPE` trustworthy in the case where the X values are different? (I can't use `LINEST` because my data has gaps.)

Comment: Can you use LINEST with zeroes replacing missing values?

Answer (score 0):

**The slope function does not always work with calculated values**.

If you are having problems with slope function giving zero values, copy and paste the data used by the slope function as values first.  The slope function does not always work with a column of calculated values.

I was trying to calculate the slope and determine how it changes with time and got only zero values.  One of the columns I was using was a moving average of 10 pressure values in another column and the cells had the green triangle “error message” Formula Omits Adjacent Values.  The calculations for this column were correct, this was just a suggestion that I was not using all the cells in the column for the calculation.  I copied and pasted the column of moving averages into another column as Values and the slope function gave the correct values when I used the new column of values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was resolved when i fixed an unrelated circular reference issue. My circular reference issue prevented any new functions referencing calculated values (rather than static values) from calculating properly.